# About Samuelson inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, optimization

If we have a set of $n$ real numbers:
$$\Omega=x_1,x_2,x_3,..,x_n$$
the arithmetic mean is:
$$A=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$$
and the standard deviation:
$$S=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-A)^2}$$
If the set of $n$ numbers are bounded so that:
$$m\le x_i\le M$$ a refinement of Samuelson inequality proven by Bhatia and Davies is:
$$S^2\le (M-A)(A-m)$$
My question is: when the equality holds? Does the equaliity hold for any kind of distribution of the numbers in $\Omega?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $i$ we see that  $S^2$ is a convex function of $x_i$, which says:
$$\max_{m\leq x\leq M}S^2=\max_{x_i\in\{m,M\}}S^2.$$
Id est, the equality occurs for  $x_1=x_2=...=x_k=m$ and $x_{k+1}=...=x_n=M.$

Now, we need to choose a value of $k$, for which we'll get a maximal value.

I hope it will help.